# htaccess rewrite and redirect rule not working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

We are migrating one of our sites from windows to linux. We have following code in web.config

```
<rewriteMaps>
<rewriteMap name="CodeRewrite">
<add key="/abc" value="/abc-product.html" />
</rewriteMap>
<rewriteMap name="CodeRedirect">
<add key="/abc-product.html" value="/abc" />
</rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

Now,
(1) If I browse [www.domain.com/abc](http://www.domain.com/abc), it will load the content from abc-product.html
(2) If I browse [www.domain.com/abc-product.html](http://www.domain.com/abc-product.html), it will redirect to [www.domain.com/abc](http://www.domain.com/abc) and load the content of abc-product.html file

How can I do this in htaccess file? I tried many option. But, nothing worked.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?abc-product.html/?$ /abc
Redirect /abc-product.html /abc
```

Can someone please suggest on this?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown attempts, samples; please try following htaccess Rules. Please make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
##Rules for internal rewrite for url http://localhost:80/abc.
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1-product\.html -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.html [L]

##Rules for external redirect and internal rewrite for url http://localhost:80/abc-product.html.    
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(abc)-product\.html\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /$1? [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(abc)/?$ abc-product.html [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. The following code worked the way exactly we were looking for:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc$ abc-product.html [L]
RewriteRule ^abc-product.html$ abc [R=301,L]
```

/abc will read the content from abc-product.html file. And if someone browses the URL with abc-product.html, it will be redirected to /abc. Updating the thread for those who are planning to do a similar setup.